# How to Iterate through List of Map<Object,Long>

Tags: java, list, loops, object, hashmap

I want to get values from this List:

```
List<Map<CategoryModel,Long>> list = categoryRespository.findSalesByCategory();
```

I print values ​​from list like this:

```
for (Map<CategoryModel, Long> categoryModelLongMap : list) {
    System.out.println(categoryModelLongMap.values());
}
```

Output:

```
[computers, 0]
[mouses, 0]
[keyboards, 0]
[laptops, 0]
```

But now i want to add these values to another map, as they appear above. I wrote something like that but it doesnt work

```
    Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map<CategoryModel, Long> featureService : list) {
        for (Map.Entry<CategoryModel,Long> entry : featureService.entrySet()) {
            newMap.put(String.valueOf(entry.getKey()), String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
{number=0, category_name=laptops}
```

Map<String, String> newMap, should be Map<String, Long>, but i dont know how to dispose of those "number" and "category_name". Objecy CategoryModel have also method "getCategoryName" which return String.  Can someone help me how can i iterate through values in list?

Comment: That `categoryModelLongMap.values()` should produce a bunch of `long` numbers, but the output you've posted is something different. *"method `getCategoryName` which return `String`"* - fine, but you're not using it in the code.

Comment: Yes, i just mentioned this, becouse i dont know how to get these values from Map. All I'm trying to do is make the new map look like:
key = laptops value = 0, key = computers value = 0, key = keyboards value = 0, key = mouses value = 0,

Comment: What you're doing in the code is confusing. Can you, please, explain what should be the end result in plain English? Do you want to **add up** all the values associated with each distinct `CategoryModel` together, and generate a map of type `Map<String, Long>` as a result where key is a name obtained via `getCategoryName()` and the value is the total amount for each category?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean, sorry for my confusing explanation

Comment: `That's exactly what I mean` - then you can borrow this description and copy-past it to the question to make it more clear to the readers.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be using something like this:

Instead of

```
    Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<>();

for (Map<CategoryModel, Long> featureService : list) {
    for (Map.Entry<CategoryModel,Long> entry : featureService.entrySet()) {
        newMap.put(String.valueOf(entry.getKey()), String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
    }
}
```

Use

```
    Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<>();
                    
                        for (Map<CategoryModel, Long> featureService : list) {
                            for (Map.Entry<CategoryModel,Long> entry : featureService.entrySet()) {
                    String rawKeyReturn = String.valueOf(entry.getKey());            
                    String rawValueReturn = String.valueOf(entry.getValue());   
                newMap.put(
        rawKeyReturn.substring(rawKeyReturn.indexOf("=")+1,rawKeyReturn.length()), 
                
rawValueReturn.substring(rawValueReturn.indexOf("=")+1,rawValueReturn.length())
                );
         }           
  }
```

Apologies for the formatting, I am not sure how to fix the spacing in the code blocks.

This solution works by finding just creating a substring of the results of your calls to the valueOf() method and cutting off the label (everything up to and including the first = sign).

There may be more elegant ways to do this, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Its okay, but its return only one row: category_name: laptops, number 0. How i can return other 3 categories?

Comment: Are you sure that List<Map<CategoryModel,Long>> list = categoryRespository.findSalesByCategory(); is filling the list with more than just the laptops? The loop you already had should be able to iterate through multiple already.

Comment: Also I would recommend considering Alexander's answer, as it is more uniform/less janky using the methods of classes you are already using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flatten the entries of each map in the List.

And then group the data associated with each distinct `CategoryModel` and add up the values mapped to the same key.

Basically, this can be done using two nested loops (your attempt was close).

That how it can be implemented using Java 8 method [`Map.merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)):

```
List<Map<CategoryModel,Long>> list = categoryRespository.findSalesByCategory();
    
Map<String, Long> result = new HashMap<>();

for (Map<CategoryModel, Long> categoryModelLongMap : list) {
    for (Map.Entry<CategoryModel, Long> entry : categoryModelLongMap.entrySet()) {
        result.merge(entry.getKey().getCategoryName(),
                     entry.getValue(),
                     Long::sum);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, it can be done using Stream API.

## groupingBy + summingLong

You can generate a stream over the list. Flatten the entries of each `Map` using `flatMap()` operation, and then apply `collect()`.

Collector [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) would group the entries having the same category, and the downstream collector [`summingLong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingLong(java.util.function.ToLongFunction)) would aggregate the values associated with the same key.

```
List<Map<CategoryModel,Long>> list = categoryRespository.findSalesByCategory();
    
Map<String, Long> result = list.stream()
    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        entry -> entry.getKey().getCategoryName(),
        Collectors.summingLong(Map.Entry::getValue)
    ));
```

## toMap

Similarly, you can use *three-args* version of Collector [`toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)):

```
List<Map<CategoryModel,Long>> list = categoryRespository.findSalesByCategory();
    
Map<String, Long> result = list.stream()
    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        entry -> entry.getKey().getCategoryName(),
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        Long::sum
    ));
```